# Yocto access sysroot files from another recipee

Tags: yocto

Say that I have two recipe's

`baselib` and `mylib`

`baselib` installs `/etc/baseversion.txt`
1.2.3.4

`mylib` Should generate `/etc/myversion.txt`
1.2.3.4-myrev1

Where `1.2.3.4` is taken from `baselib`.

How do I access the version from `baselib`?

Comment: Version is in the file name: `baselib_1.2.3.4.bb` ou `baselib_git.bb` and inside file include `PV="1.2.3.4"`

Comment: To get the version use: `PV_baselib`